# getting error while installing libxml2

Tags: python, xml, python-2.x

I am trying to install `libxml2` for Python version 2.7.3, but whenever I try to install it gives me error:

> failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir

Looking for a work-around solution please help

P.S. I am on Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 1):

There is the huge list of **Unofficial Windows Binaries** for Python Extension Packages which are extremely useful for Windows users.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Go to the link and search for libxml-python and install it and you are good to go.

Cheers !